# get number of element greater than 0 in column

Tags: matlab, matrix

in matrix, I want to get the number of element in a column which has a value greater than 0. For example i have a matrix like that;

```
1  2  4  5
0  0  1  2
1  1  1  1

xi = number of element which is greater than 0 in column i.

then, x1=2, x2=2, x3=3, x4=3
```

But I must do this without loop. (id I use loop, computation time gets really high)

Comment: Rather try and get a vector that holds each result in a separate element than creating 4 variables with different names as that is very bad practice. i.e. rather have `x(1)=2` and `x(2)=2` etc

Comment: it is just an example. my array size is too big and i just want number of element greater than zero for computation of another formula. i wont store them @Dan

Comment: So are you asking how to do this inside a loop when iterating over the columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your matrix is `A`, then do:

```
X = sum(A>0,1);
```

Each element of `X` contain the number of elements greater than zero in a column.

Best